# Prove a combinatorial identity with a combinatorial argument

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}\cdot\dbinom{n}{k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$$

**Attempt:** 
I have re-written in it as follows:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dbinom{k}{1}\dbinom{k}{1}\dbinom{n}{k} = \dbinom{n}{1}\dbinom{n+1}{1}  2^{n-2}$$

the LHS seems like a case where a committee of k people is to be formed from n people. We choose a president in k ways. Then, we choose a secretary in k ways again. Which means that the president could be chosen as a secretary as well? (probably not the best example). 
How can I use the RHS to show the same thing?

Comment: Perhaps thinking about RHS as $\binom{n+1}{2}2^{n-1}$ instead would help?

Answer (score 2):

> Algebriac Proof:

Rewrite $k^2=k(k-1)+k$. We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}  k^2 \binom{n}{k} &=&  \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k-1) \binom{n}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom{n}{k} \\
&=& n(n-1) \sum_{k=2}^{n} \binom{n-2}{k-2} + n \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \\
&=& n(n-1) 2^{n-2} + n 2^{n-1} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

> Combinatorial Proof:

We choose a committee of size $k$ from $n$ people and then choose a president & secretary (possible the same person). This is the LHS

For the RHS there are $2$ case.

$1)$ Choose the president ($n$ ways) and secretary ($n-1$ ways) to be a different from the president & then the rest of the committee ($2^{n-2}$ ways.)

$2)$ Choose the president & secretary to be the same person ($n$ ways) and the rest of the committee ($2^{n-1}$ ways.)

Now add these to get the result.

Comment: Would you mind running the first sum in the second line from $2$ to $n$?

Comment: @user5713492 Yes you could do that ... of course the $k=1$ term is zero.

Comment: Thanks, however, my textbook required that I use a combinatorial argument. I do appreciate the algebraic proof.

Comment: @D_M You are very nearly there with the combinatorial proof in your question ... give me a couple of mins ... I will update my answer.